# Synchronize Changes from Percona MySql to Couchbase

Tags: mysql, couchbase, percona

We're deploying Couchbase as a caching solution for our web application. We're looking for a reliable manner to synchronize changes to the database to the caching tier. This could be done in the application tier; however, this leads to the potential for stale records or potential cache updates made before a transaction completes. Have done some cursory exploration of UDF capabilities to solve this problem using a trigger. Anyone have any recommendations or experience with other customers solving this problem?